# CSV to GeoJSON in C++

Tags: geojson, convert, csv, c++, library

I'm looking for a way of converting CSV file to GeoJSON in C++

I'm currently writing a conversion function that writes a text file with the structure of a GeoJSON file, but this isn't really sexy. Maybe is there a library, or a well done function to do it properly?

Comment: OGR is the standard approach to this

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to convert from one vector format to another you should check if [GDAL/OGR](http://www.gdal.org/) is the answer (hint: unless you use Java it is).

It provides a [CSV driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html) to read in your data and [GeoJSON driver](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html) to write it out, and a handy [tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html) to help get you started.